# How to restrict build failure emails to only a specific branch in travis CI?

Tags: github, build, travis-ci

I have email and slack notifications configured for travis build failures. Currently It sends notifications for build failure of every branch. Since every developer does creates lot of branches, the mails come in a large number which sound like spam. I would want to restrict the mails only for failures of develop branch.

My configuration in .travis.yml is something like this.

```
notifications:
   email:
    recipients:
     - xyz@abc.com
    branches:
      only: develop
    on_success: change
    on_failure: always
```

Is this branch specific alerts are really supported, if yes how do you do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your specific query about if **branch specific notification** is supported by Travis currently, the answer is **NO**. Below is from the [Travis documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#changing-notification-frequency):

> There is currently no way of limiting the notification to a specific branch, but the payload will contain all relevant data to do so at the receiving end

So currently the branch specific notification is not supported by Travis, but would need to be implemented separately by consuming the webhook payload from Travis.

**Update:**
(Courtesy @LucasCimon) There is an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1405) to track this feature request.

Comment: This GitHub issue tracks this feature request by the way : https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1405

Comment: Thanks for sharing @LucasCimon. Have added the update.

Comment: On the other hand, at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/#conditional-notifications it says "You can filter out and reject notifications by specifying a condition in your build configuration (your .travis.yml file) using `if`" (but it doesn't work for me, I still get all notifications...)